# SSIS - exporting multiple resultsets from stored procedure to multiple sheets in an Excel

Tags: ssis

I have been creating a SSIS package where the procedure I use returns 3 result sets and this needs to be copied over to a single excel with 3 different sheets. I have used a script component to extract the data, defined 3 outputs and used data reader to map results to those outputs. I added paths to 3 different Excel file destination (all pointing to same file but different sheets). When I run the package it works fine once every 5/6 times but mostly it fails with below error.

Could anyone help me why it keeps failing most of the time and how to fix it.

Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination 1 [366]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination 1 [366]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Excel Destination Input" (377)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Excel Destination Input" (377)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Excel Destination 1" (366) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Excel Destination Input" (377). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Can you supply more detail? e.g. queries, what the data you are querying looks like, etc. What have you tried?

Comment: Might be an order of operations issue.   If you are populating the Excel sheets in parallel, try doing it sequentially forcing it to be in order (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3).

Comment: Tab - Thanks, contention was the issue. Once I started to populate the sheets one after the other, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write to all three sheets in parallel can cause contention issues.   Redesign your package to force the three dataflows to run in sequence (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3) and the issue will go away.